# Using my zsh with personal configuration inside a Docker

Tags: docker, zsh, contains

Is it possible to have my zsh setup with my aliases, theme and other settings run inside a docker container?

Typically, I use containers for development and often utilize different and new images. I suppose there must be a way to run my zsh inside these containers, but I wonder if there is some way to configure it once with minimal adjustments required for using it with new images (since I guess applying it to new images is too much to ask).

I would like to have some configuration that includes my personal settings, aliases, GitHub & AWS credentials, etc., so that when developing in interactive mode inside a docker, I'll have a similar experience to running a virtual environment.

Comment: I don't know where you have stored your personal configuration, but if this location is made accessible to the container, you can use the environment variable `ZDOTDIR` to tell zsh where to look for them.

Comment: Hi, thanks! Do you mean that `ZDOTDIR` tells zsh where to find the `.zshrc` file? That might help, but this assumes that zsh is already installed inside the container right? That way, I will have to configure the installation, mount the location of `.zshrc`, and set the env variable each time. I guess that might work, but I wish I could find something as simple as `conda activate myenv` instead of configuring the image, building it, and setting mounts and flags each time.

Comment: Yes. Read the _zshall_ man-page. It's not only this file, but also the location of some other ones which you perhaps are using (`.zlogout` for instance). If you pass to your container the environment variable `ZDOTDIR` when you start the container, zsh will find it in its environment and pick it up.